# When does a homogeneous space define a fibration?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, fibration, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a locally compact and $\sigma$-compact group acting continuously and transitively on locally compact Hausdorff $X$. Then if $x_0 \in X$ and $H_{x_0}$ denotes the isotropy group at $x_0$ we have the homeomorphism $G/H_{x_0} \overset{\phi}{\simeq} X$, $\phi(gH_{x_0}) = gx_0$. Is it true that we always have a fibration $H_{x_0} \hookrightarrow G \to X$? If not, what are sufficient conditions to have a fibration?

Comment: I know that if $H_{x_0}$ is closed, $(G,X,H_{x_0})$ defines a fiber bundle. I don't know what you mean by fibration, but usually it is more general than fiber bundle, and so is true.

Comment: @TroyWoo very nice, can you give a reference please? By (Hurewicz) fibration I mean that it satisfies the homotopy lifting property w.r.t. any topological space.

Comment: Find the classic book Steenrod Topology of Fibre Bundles CUP 1960, starting from Page 28.

Comment: @TroyWoo According to this book, we have a fibre bundle if the projection map $G \to G/H_{x_0}$ admits a local cross section near identity.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that.